# Correct collision handling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

First of all, this will be Open Source, and you will be mentioned for the help.

---

We've been programming a Super Mario Remake for the iPhone with Cocos2d for school.
It looks pretty great, and we decided to make it Open Source, because we can't get any profit because of Copyright issues.

We programmed the physics on our own, but it has a few issues.

Collisions are constantly checked, and this is how I do it:

---

### Collision Handling

```
- (void)updateCollisions:(ccTime)delta {
    for (STGameObject *child in self.gameObjects) {
        for (STGameObject *child2 in self.gameObjects) {
            // Don't check same object
            if (child == child2) {
                break;
            }

            if (STRectIntersect(child.boundingBox, child2.boundingBox)) {
                // Position objects
                STRectEdge edge1 = [self updateCollisionOfGameObject:child withGameObject:child2 delta:delta];
                STRectEdge edge2 = [self updateCollisionOfGameObject:child2 withGameObject:child delta:delta];

                // Send notifications
                [child collisionWithGameObject:child2 edge:edge1];
                [child2 collisionWithGameObject:child edge:edge2];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (STRectEdge)updateCollisionOfGameObject:(STGameObject *)gameObject
                           withGameObject:(STGameObject *)gameObject2
                                    delta:(ccTime)delta {

    STRectEdge rectEdge;
    float edgeLeft = (gameObject.boundingBox.origin.x - gameObject2.boundingBox.origin.x - gameObject.boundingBox.size.width) * -1;
    float edgeRight = (gameObject.boundingBox.origin.x + gameObject2.boundingBox.size.width - gameObject2.boundingBox.origin.x);
    float edgeTop = (gameObject.boundingBox.origin.y + gameObject.boundingBox.size.height - gameObject2.boundingBox.origin.y);
    float edgeBottom = (gameObject.boundingBox.origin.y - gameObject2.boundingBox.size.height - gameObject2.boundingBox.origin.y) * -1;

    float offset = 0.0;
    if (edgeLeft < edgeRight) {
        rectEdge = STRectEdgeMinX;
        offset = edgeLeft;
    } else {
        rectEdge = STRectEdgeMaxX;
        offset = edgeRight;
    }

    if (edgeTop < edgeBottom) {
        float cached = edgeTop;
        if (cached < offset) {
            rectEdge = STRectEdgeMaxY;
            offset = cached;
        }
    } else {
        float cached = edgeBottom;
        if (cached < offset) {
            rectEdge = STRectEdgeMinY;
            offset = cached;
        }
    }

    if (gameObject.bodyType != STGameObjectBodyTypeStatic) {
        if (gameObject2.bodyType != STGameObjectBodyTypeStatic) {
            offset /= 2.0;
        }

        if ([gameObject bodyType] != STGameObjectBodyTypeNonColliding && [gameObject2 bodyType] != STGameObjectBodyTypeNonColliding) {
            switch (rectEdge) {
                case STRectEdgeMinX:
                {
                    [gameObject move:ccp(offset, 0)];
                }
                    break;
                case STRectEdgeMaxX:
                {
                    [gameObject move:ccp(-offset, 0)];
                }
                    break;
                case STRectEdgeMinY:
                {
                    [gameObject move:ccp(0, offset)];
                }
                    break;
                case STRectEdgeMaxY:
                {
                    [gameObject move:ccp(0, -offset)];
                }
                    break;
            }

            if (rectEdge == STRectEdgeMinY && gameObject.velocity.y < 0) {
                gameObject.velocity = ccp(gameObject.velocity.x, 0);
            }
            if (rectEdge == STRectEdgeMaxY && gameObject.velocity.y > 0) {
                gameObject.velocity = ccp(gameObject.velocity.x, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    return rectEdge;
}
```

---

It basically checks which collision edge of the rect is the smallest (easiest to adjust).
The problem now is the following

[image: CollisionProblem]

As you can see, if Mario collapses a brick at it's bottom edge, it will look like there was a collision at the minimum Y edge. However, this is not the case. This causes to constantly destroy blocks, even though there was no real collision at this edge, but rather at the minimum X edge.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: my comment is just theoretical...can't you use a let's say boolean value that tells you if a brick can be broken or not ? And if it can, just proceed as normal...if it can't be broken, then it remains

Comment: @Teshte Hehe, that's not the problem. Yes, I used the wrong brick sprites here. But those bricks SHOULD be breakable. Just not that way. The should be breakable with a Koopa armor, for example. But the collision is incorrect, and there are more problems just like this one.

Comment: what should happen in this case?

Comment: @Teshte Mario should just be pushed to the left, and the brick should remain.

Comment: IMO, you would need some boolean values for the bricks and some for mario...for example..if mario has a `KoopaArmor = true`, and a brick has `destroyedBy = [KoopaArmor, head]`, then mario could destroy this brick by jumping (the head value from the array) or if he has a koopa armor...And when a collision happens you make those checks..if none apply, then nothing happens

Comment: @Teshte I don't think that's necessary. I already have a property to see if the block is destroyable. Look, the destroyable block must be destroyable by Mario, or the Koopa armor. But there is just no way Mario can get under that block, to destroy it. It's not that it shouldn't be destroyable, but rather that it's not possible that way. Also, one can destroy the lowest block, and then destroy the upper blocks with jumping...

Comment: ok i get it...then maybe a solution would be to verify the colission from mario's top like this : instead of verifying the entire width of Mario, let 5px to the left, and 5 to the right for example...what this will do, is to allow the distruction of the block by jumping, but only if the impact is closer to marios head (rather then the hand...)  Do you think this could work?

Comment: @Teshte Theoretically, yes. But it seems hackish, and I'm trying to make it as dynamic as possible...

Comment: another thing that might work is once a collision by Marios top was detected, to perform 2 other verifications, and see if there is a collision to the right or to the left. If any of these 2 also exists (and they are bricks not enemies) that means that you should ignore the top one and only the second should have any effect on the game (because what i basically described here is the problem you have)

Comment: @Teshte Hm.. I can see. But there is always a "collision" on either side. It's the 2d, the x and y have to collide for a collision to happen.

Comment: and now we return to something i said earlier...for me a top colision is the entire width of Mario, having 1 px height, (lets say 30px x 1px) the bottom is the same. The right and left, are Marios height -2 px (1 from the top and one from the bottom), and also they have 1 px in width (so basically you check with these 4 lines, not mario's entire width*height rectangle)...and this way a colision on the top, doesn't always mean a collision on the right or left

Comment: copyright: whether the game will be open source or commercial, distributing copyrighted content (mario graphics) without permission is a copyright violation, period!

Comment: @NSAddict I guess you will also have to change some colors :)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D You're right, I will remove the tiled map and create some of my own.

Comment: @Teshte Not really. I have a velocity, which is added to the sprites position every frame. The sprite can overlap a lot more than just one px. But you should be able to destroy a block, even if you're not standing exactly underneath it.

Comment: idk why this is happening : `The sprite can overlap a lot more than just one px` but because of it my solution will not work...i kinda of ran out of ideas...good luck

Comment: @Teshte Haha that's ok man, that's why I'm here too ;)
The sprite can have a velocity, and for it to move faster, I have to increase the velocity. If the velocity is not `1` all the time, obviously chances are, that it will overlap more than just 1px...

Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Cocos2D, I recommend you to take a look at `Box2D` for the collision detection. More info here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone

Comment: The game is already finished. This is the only issue that's remaining.
I'd have to change half of the game-logic to switch to Box2D

Comment: OK sorry than, my answer is not suitable for you. Based on comments above: what about to keep some manually adjusted "real" texture frame for each sprite? I expect all the sprites be the same size, lets say `100x100` for example. When the mario stands still, the frame could be like `(0, 10)(100,90)` (staning still, touches bottom, has some space on top). When running (in the air), the frame would be `(0,0)(100,90)` (in the air, to the top, some space at the bottom). And calculate the collision against this "real content" frame